# Parts on a Raspberry PI

Tags: hardware

I saw on the board that there were two things that looked like a processor. I know that the bigger one is the processor but what is the smaller one? I don't remember what is written on it but I hope someone can include it in their answer.

Comment: Welcome. Please ask more precise questions next time. You should read the FAQ also. Upvote and accept answers that helped you.

Comment: (on the Pi 1, 2 & 3 currently) The big bit is the System on a Chip - this basically has things like the GPU, CPU, RAM, etc - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/README.md. The other smaller big chip controls the USB and Ethernet ports https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/usb/README.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking about but here is the low level breakdown of what is on the Pi.

[image]

And here is the descriptive layout

[image]

**You can find out more about the [Raspberry Pi on Wikipeda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) and searching the internet using your favourite search engine.**

Comment: I think he is referring to the Ethernet controller.

Comment: Which is actually a combination USB hub and ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The chip you are referring to is the USB Hub adaptor which includes an intergrated enthernet adaptor.

The middle chip that you can see is actually the memory which is soldered on top of the CPU/GPU